# I am getting none with font name in some files

Tags: python, python-docx

I don't know why it tells me None. I have used Python docx library for doing this, I have tried multiple times but didn't find any satisfactory solution.

```
# Function to extract information about 'Abstract heading Font Style' from the document
def abstract_heading_font_style(word_file):
    doc = Document(word_file)
    font_styles = set() 
    
    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
        if any(word in paragraph.text for word in ['Abstract', 'ABSTRACT', 'abstract']):
            for run in paragraph.runs:      
                font_styles.add(run.font.name)
                if any(word in paragraph.text for word in ['Abstract', 'ABSTRACT', 'abstract'])and run.bold:      
                        font_styles.add(run.font.name)
            
    return list(font_styles)
```

Comment: If the paragraph is using a style, I'm not sure it has a font as part of the paragraph.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and try to communicate more clearly. "I don't know why it tells me None" - **what does this mean**? What is "it", and how is it "telling" you this? How do you *use* the `abstract_heading_font_style` function - what do you pass for the `word_file`? **Exactly what do you think should happen** when you do this, and **how can you know** if you got the right answer? **What happens instead** when you try it, and **how is that different** from what you want? What is the intended logic of the code? In your own words, why should that solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

You're adding the font style to font_styles only if run.bold is True within the nested loop so if there are no bold runs in the paragraph containing 'Abstract' it will always return None since you're not returning anything outside the loop try using below code

```
from docx import Document


def abstract_heading_font_style(word_file):
    doc = Document(word_file)
    font_styles = set() 
    
    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
        if any(word in paragraph.text for word in ['Abstract', 'ABSTRACT', 'abstract']):
            for run in paragraph.runs:
                font_styles.add(run.font.name)
    
    return list(font_styles)

#usage:
word_file = "your_word_file.docx"
abstract_fonts = abstract_heading_font_style(word_file)
print(abstract_fonts)
```